# Scanf fails with bus error

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, bus-error

I'm playing with C and I've run into this error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
 char* foo;
 scanf("%s", foo);
 printf("entered %s", foo);
 return 0;
}
```

`scanf` takes pointer, `foo` is pointer, yet I get bus error. How can I make it work?

Comment: This is a FAQ - you want `char foo[SOMESIZE];`

Comment: No you don't. But if you think you do, `char * foo = malloc( SOMESIZE );`

Comment: The way you are doing this will never be safe. This is the road to unsafe and fragile C programs, for which C is infamous: Whatever size you allocate to `foo`, a user of the program can always overflow it and cause the program to crash. Use `fgets` instead. (Note: It's not your fault. It's hard for beginners to see which functions are safe to use)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never initialize `foo`, so it points to a more or less random location in memory. Either allocate it on the stack.

```
char foo[10];
```

Or malloc it on the heap:

```
char *foo = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

But if you malloc, don't forget to free().

And watch out for buffer overflows; if something takes in a buffer but no maximum size, be very careful. You can specify a maximum length for `scanf` by doing `%9s`, for instance. `scanf` will not account for the terminating null, though, so you need to pass one less than the length of your buffer.

Comment: Note also that you *must* allocate enough space to store the string read in by scanf. If you allocate only one character, you will get undefined behavior (likely a segfault) if you type in anything but the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As to what `Bus error: 10` means:

> SIGBUS (10) / Bus error 10 means a signal sent to an application if an
> attempts is made to access memory outside of its address space. This
> may be due to bad pointer that has an invalid address in it.